# Node JS upgrade to 16.18 issue: File and Request types not found

Tags: node.js, typescript-typings

I have upgraded from Node version 14 to node version 16.8.

```
λ node --version
v16.18.0
```

What I am seeing is, when I am running `nest start --debug --watch`, once the build is done successfully, it is keep on complaining the following weird stuffs. Everything was working fine with node-js 16.5.0 earlier.

Just to give you a hint, I upgraded to node js 16.5.0 to 18.x first. But as then it was decided to use node 16.18.0. So I uninstall node js in my laptop and install nodejs 16.18.0.

The errors are something like this:

```js
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request } from 'express';

export const AuthToken = createParamDecorator(
  (data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
    const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    return getAuthToken(request);
  },
);

export const getAuthToken = (request: Request): string => {
  return request.headers['authorization']?.replace('Bearer ', '');
};
```

And the error is:

```
TS2304: Cannot find name 'Request'.
     8 | );
     9 |
  > 10 | export const getAuthToken = (request: Request): string => {
       |                                       ^^^^^^^
    11 |   return request.headers['authorization']?.replace('Bearer ', '');
    12 | };
    13 |
```

Similarly another code snippet:

```js
import fs from 'fs';
import { isUndefined } from 'lodash';
import path from 'path';

export class FileUtil {
    public saveMediatorLog(parentDir: File, instanceId: string, content: File) {
        const srcFilePath: string = `${parentDir}/instance_${instanceId}_mediatorLog.tgz`;
        const destFilePath: string = `${parentDir}/${content.name}`;
        const srcFileWithAbsolutePath = path.resolve(srcFilePath);
        const destFileAbsolutePath = path.resolve(destFilePath);
        fs.stat(srcFilePath, function(err) {
            if (isUndefined(err)) {
                fs.copyFile(srcFileWithAbsolutePath, destFileAbsolutePath, (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        throw err;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I click on File to see the definition, it leads me to:

[image]

It has a name.

But it complains this:

```
TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'File'.
     6 |     public saveMediatorLog(parentDir: File, instanceId: string, content: File) {
     7 |         const srcFilePath: string = `${parentDir}/instance_${instanceId}_mediatorLog.tgz`;
  >  8 |         const destFilePath: string = `${parentDir}/${content.name}`;
       |                                                              ^^^^
```

Some of my versions are:

```
Node Js: 16.18.0
"@types/node": "^14.14.31",
"typescript": "^4.1.5"
"ts-node": "^10.9.1",
```

I am really not able to understand where the issue is or what is the remedy.

Comment: So you upgraded from node 14 to 16.5 then to 18.x then back to 16.18? When you switch major versions, some dependencies may break. Have you tried reinstalling your dependencies or check if they are compatible with your version? And you should probably match the version of `@types/node` to your node version in use. You may also need to reinstall the globally installed packages

Comment: Thanks sir. Was tried whole day and see some light at the end of tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

For me: the issue was: yarn cache (may be some older versions were there).
So I did a forceful cache clean this:

`yarn cache clean --force`

`rm yarn.lock`

This solves the issue.

*However* there are quite a few dependency mismatches still exists which ideally I will fix over time.
Getting everything clean after upgrading to Node is not an easy task, seems:

Yarn Dependency errors:

```
warning "@nestjs/swagger > @nestjs/mapped-types@0.4.1" has incorrect peer dependency "class-transformer@^0.2.0 || ^0.3.0 || ^0.4.0".
warning " > @nestjs/typeorm@9.0.1" has incorrect peer dependency "@nestjs/common@^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0".
warning " > @nestjs/typeorm@9.0.1" has incorrect peer dependency "@nestjs/core@^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0".
warning " > @nestjs/typeorm@9.0.1" has incorrect peer dependency "rxjs@^7.2.0".
warning "@ssut/nestjs-sqs > sqs-consumer@5.7.0" has incorrect peer dependency "aws-sdk@^2.1114.0".
warning " > swagger-ui-express@4.4.0" has unmet peer dependency "express@>=4.0.0".
warning " > @nestjs/schematics@8.0.11" has incorrect peer dependency "typescript@^3.4.5 || ^4.3.5".
warning " > ts-loader@8.3.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@*".
```

A better option is to try `npm install` for such a case. As `npm` builds the dependency sequentially (yarn does it as parallel as possible), you will get step by step errors. (Of course you can override it using `--legacy-peer-deps` like this):

`npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

Without this you will get very nice errors like this:

```
# npm resolution error report

2022-11-05T13:47:27.128Z

While resolving: gradual-deploy@0.0.1
Found: @nestjs/common@7.6.18
node_modules/@nestjs/common
  @nestjs/common@"^7.6.13" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer @nestjs/common@"^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0" from @nestjs/typeorm@9.0.1
node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm
  @nestjs/typeorm@"^9.0.1" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I tried to manually resolves one by one. But the issue is: at the runtime there were so much dependency mismatches, I lost.

So I clean up the yarn cache and take a shortcut to unblock myself.